# Select2 Dropdowns do not close once opened

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2-4

I am using select2 version 4. If I click on the various dropdowns, they all remain open even if I click on them or on the screen. This does not happen on Chrome, only Internet Explorer and Eclipse's internal web browser. However, they do close if I select two options from a particluar dropdown.

I am unable to post images so I'll just post my code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" import = "java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sisyphus/1.1.103/sisyphus.min.js"></script>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-rc.1/css/select2.min.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-rc.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <title>SELECT2</title>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h1 align = center>SELECT2</h1><br><br>
        <div align = center>
                <form id = "myForm" method = "post">
                <%
                    int i, j;
                for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                %>
                <div class="container">    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">  
                            <div class="panel-body">                        
                            <select style = "width:250px;" multiple="multiple" name = "First[<%= i %>]" >
                            <%
                                for(j = 1; j < 5; j++)
                                {
                                %>
                                <option value = "First<%= j %>">First Option<%= j  %></option>
                                <%
                                }
                            %>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                            <select style = "width:250px;" multiple="multiple" name = "Second[<%= i %>]" >
                           <%
                                for(j = 1; j < 5; j++)
                                {
                                %>
                                <option value = "Second<%= j %>">Second Option<%= j  %></option>
                                <%
                                }
                            %>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <%
                i++;
                } 
                %>
                <br><br>
                <input type= submit class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value = "Submit" />
                <br><br>
                </form>

        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
    $( function() {
          $("#myForm").sisyphus({
            timeout: 0
          });

          $("select").select2({
              placeholder: "Select an action",
              closeOnSelect: true
          });

          $("select").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
              var element = evt.params.data.element;
              var $element = $(element); 
              $element.detach();
              $(this).append($element);
              $(this).trigger("change");
            });



    });

    </script>


</html>
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Edit: As pointed out by Sylvan, I moved the form out of the for loop. That did not help though.

Comment: Probably not a solution, but you should either change `myForm` to a *class* or add `count i`, since IDs are meant to be unique and due to your `for-loop` you have several forms with the same ID

Comment: @SylvanDAsh you are right, I moved the form tag out of the for loop. Did not help my problem though but thanks for noticing it.

Comment: Probably the `multiple` attribute on the `select` elements could be the problem. Perhaps there's an option for it in `select2`?

Comment: According to the [Select2 documentation](https://select2.github.io/examples.html), the multiple attribute can be used the way I have.